# Calculator app approach

Tags: android, calculator

as getting into android i decided to replace the default calculator with mine. A simple calculator with the 4 operational signs. I've been giving to all buttons the right behaviour, storing every number in a 'num' ArrayList(String) and signs in a 'sign' ArrayList(String).

What i wanted to do, was to then combine numbers and signs into a string, parse it into a float and getting a result. I thought this was one of the easy/simple ways to deal with it, since when you set a float like this:

```
float f = 6*4-5/2+3
```

it gives you the right result. but it clearly does not when starting from a String, like this:

```
String s = "6*4-5/2+3"
Float f = Float.valueOf(s)
```

Is there a way to getting a result from my 2 ArrayList(String)? In the negative case, what would be a doable approach (in the sense im not an experienced programmer)I?

Comment: Use DijkstraTwoStack Algorithm for expression evaluation. This will help you in solving the problem if you want i will add the code in answer?

Comment: have a look at this library http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/

Comment: Hey @AnuranjitMaindolan and A.S.. Ill have a look at both your ideas. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I Think this approach is incorrect.
I would do the following:

You would have a Textview or Edittext as the calculator "screen" on top.

then you would have all your number and operation signs buttons.

Now, every number you press, it will append to the last one on the screen, using `.append()`

once you tap on an operator sign - two things will happen:

1) the number in the textView will be stored as a Float (using `Float.valueOf(yourTextView);` in a varibale, say `firstNum`.

2) you will save the operator you clicked in a second variable, say String `calcOper`.

Now, you enter your second number, and then you would press the Equals sign.

What will happen then is simply use a `Switch` of `If` expression.

If `calcOper` is "-" - then do `firstNum`- Current number shown on screen.

If `calcOper` is "+" - then do `firstNum`+ Current number shown on screen.

At last don't forget to set the text on the TextView  the result.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks! The problem is that i want to be able to perform multiple and longer operations. So i need to be able to store more numbers, not just 2. And i can't perform the first operation, and then the second and then the third and so on, because in case i have this '6+4/2' i would need to do 4/2 and only then 6+ the result of the previous.

Comment: About storing more numbers it is not a problem - you just store the result in a third variable. About long Chain operations I can think of a solution but it is long and complicated - I'm sure there are much better answers out there :-)